# Android6 permissions off by default

Tags: android

After installing the application for Android6, all the permissions is turned off by default. How to make them enabled by default?

Answer (score 2):

Don't set targetSdkVersion to 23 , to be free from RunTime Permision Problems.

Answer (score 1):

Permission in android 6 will be off by default and you can not simply make them on without users intervention. you will have to make necessary changes in your app to adapt for new permission model.

refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for more details on how you can adapt to new permission model.